# WebSphere Liberty: Error parsing /META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty, ear

I am creating an EAR file which has multiple WARs as module but when I try to deploy the EAR module of the project on WebSphere Liberty I get below error saying that

```
/META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi deployment descriptor on line 5. The error message was: ParseError
```

I have not even used EJB anywhere in my project and not even ejb word is mentioned anywhere in complete project module. I have not created ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi but the Liberty is still looking for ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi.

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0106E: Could not start web application BKS_EAR.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0004E: An exception occurred while starting the application BKS_EAR. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.metadata.MetaDataException: com.ibm.wsspi.adaptable.module.UnableToAdaptException: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: com.ibm.wsspi.adaptable.module.UnableToAdaptException: com.ibm.ws.javaee.ddmodel.DDParser$ParseException: CWWKC2272E: An error occurred while parsing the /META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi deployment descriptor on line 5. The error message was: ParseError at [row,col]:[5,93]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?ejbExtensions&xsi:type&xsi
```

This was previously working fine but once I deleted project from workspace and re-imported it using maven import I am facing this issue.

Comment: The error message indicates Liberty is finding that file, and having trouble parsing it. So I would suggest removing it and see what happens.

Comment: @alasdair: I made sure that file does not exist in the project but still web sphere is looking for it.